# Showing different Size of an Image based on the Width Available

Tags: jquery, html, layout

I have a two column layout on my website which has over 100 slides on it. Each Slide contains an image and a video on it. Some slides have video on them and some doesn't. Since both Image and Video are on the same row, they share the width of the slide as 50% - 50%.

Now, my question is that I how can I make the width of the Image as 100% automatically if there is no video on the slide. This should happen on Page Load as all the slides are loaded simultaneously where user then slides left or right.

Following is the HTML:-

```
<div class="body-content">  
    <h1 class="content-title">
        Heading
    </h1>
    <p>
        // This is the Main Image.
        <img src=".jpg Link comes here"></p>

        // This is the Side Video. On Pages without video, this DIV wouldn't exist.
        <div class="profile-video red-border">  
        <div class="field field-name-field-video field-type-file field-label-hidden">
            <div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even">
                <div class="jwplayer-video">
                  <div id="77efb90a6cda2b6853724f33b58f33e7_wrapper" style="position: relative; width: 133px; height: 168px;">
                    <object tag for Video>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Hopefully, I guess some JQuery would be able to help me here.

Thanks.

Comment: This type of math can be handled at the server level. How do you generate the HTML on this page?

Comment: Through Drupal. I was hoping that I could add in a JQuery in the header file which checks if the Video Div is present inside the `body-content` div, then it just changes its CSS and we can control the widths.

Comment: of course, but it's best to put the load on the server where possible, because you never know the specs of the client, they may be poor.    `if(!$('profile-video').length){ $('img').addClass('myClassWhenVideoIsMissing'); }`